# content_extra_field_weight() function in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, entities

I am porting a module to Drupal 6. I came across this function content_extra_field_weight(), what is the similar function in Drupal 7 for content_extra_field_weight()?

Answer (score 1):

Invoke [hook_field_extra_fields()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_extra_fields/7), pass the result to  [hook_field_extra_fields_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_extra_fields_alter/7) and look for *weight* keys in the result.